# Exception after reading values from jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am inserting values into database but I am getting UIException here is my code sample,

```
public void createTeacherInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
            try{

                TeacherInfo teacherInfo= new TeacherInfo();
                request.getParameter("flowName");
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");

                String tId= request.getParameter("teacherId");
                teacherInfo.setTeahcerId(Integer.parseInt(tId));

                //teacherInfo.setTeahcerId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("teacherId")));
                teacherInfo.setTeacherName(request.getParameter("teacherName"));
                /*teacherInfo.setDob(df.parse(request.getParameter("dob")));
                teacherInfo.setDoj(df.parse(request.getParameter("doj")));*/
                teacherInfo.setTeacherEducation(request.getParameter("education"));
                teacherInfo.setPreviousEmployeDetails(request.getParameter("prevdetails"));
                //teacherInfo.setYearOfExper(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("experience")));
                teacherInfo.setTeahcherPhoto(request.getParameter("photo"));
                teacherInfo.setTeacherEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
                System.out.println(tId);
                System.out.println("TeacherId");
                pupilInfoManagementBusinessService.createTeacherInfo(teacherInfo);

                }catch (BusinessException e) {
                    webLayerLogger.error(CommonUtils.getStackTrace(e));
                    throw new UIException(e,UIMessageHelper.getLocalValue("exception while Inserting data"));
                }
}
```

In this method after reading all values it will go to service method , Here is service class method,

```
@Override
public void createTeacherInfo(TeacherInfo teacherInfo) throws BusinessException {
    try {
         pupilInfoManagementDataService.createTeacherInfo(teacherInfo);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        businessServiceLogger.error(CommonUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new BusinessException(this.getClass(), e, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

My problem is values are reading but not inserting to database. Please help me in this .

Comment: Please show the stack trace

Comment: post ur code that inserts into the database

Comment: oh yes pls wait . . I will.

Comment: this is my stacktrace.               com.qualstech.web.common.UIException: exception while Inserting data
 at com.magnasoft.northstar.web.pupil.PupilInfoManagementHelper.createTeacherInfo(PupilInfoManagementHelper.java:1194)
 at com.magnasoft.northstar.web.pupil.PupilInfoManagementController.doProcess(PupilInfoManagementController.java:845)

Comment: Actualy I am not writing code to insert , I am using Ibaties framework for that . but I am new to this kind of programming

Comment: this excpetion is the one which is throwd, we need the root of all evel, its logget at ´webLayerLogger.error(CommonUtils.getStackTrace(e));´

Comment: Sorry I didnt get it . .

Comment: We need the stack Trace of the exception throwed by `pupilInfoManagementDataService.createTeacherInfo(teacherInfo);` to determ whats the problem, you are showing us `throw new UIException(e,UIMessageHelper.getLocalValue("exception while Inserting data"));`

Comment: Stack traces are nothing but "you will have some lines in your server log" wen u are executing the above code

Comment: ya that is only I commented before . .

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet the html form for this includes a file upload for the photo.  When a form includes a file upload, then `request.getParameter` will not work any longer (the values will always be `null`). When you do a file upload you have to use [Apache Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) library to retrieve the parameters from the request, or you can use `request.getPart` (if you are on the latest version of your servlet container).